# Swedish Characters in .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have a problem with .htaccess RewriteRule while using swedish characters (ä,ö.å)

i have rule written in my .htaccess file is..

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
```

Working fine. when I type `Http://www.mydomain.se/Läga-till`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-&-(.*)/$ index.php [NC,L]
```

but it does not work when i write this rule..

```
RewriteRule ^Läga-till/$ index.php [NC,L]
```

can anyone help me out resolving this issue??..

its been more than a week but could find the right solution for it yet.. :('

Comment: Do you get any error or do it give page not found?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the first rule works for the URL that you gave, but the URI looks like this:

```
Läga-till
```

And your regular expression matching the URI looks like this:

```
^Läga-till/$
```

So there's a trailing slash that doesn't match. Try changing the regex to:

```
^Läga-till/?$
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteRule ^Läga-till/([^/]+)/?$ index.asp?page=om-mig&subpage=$1 [NC,L,NU]
```